# nlog logger and filters

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I want to apply a filter to stop certain errors coming through via email but still have them logged to a file

f is a file target and m is the mail target, both working fine until i apply this filter:

```
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="f" /> 
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="m" >
    <filters>
      <when condition="contains(${message}, 'Some message exception text')" action="Ignore" />
    </filters>
  </logger>
</rules>
```

If an error is thrown that contains 'Some message exception text' I was expecting an entry to still appear in the file log but it doesn't. I don't receive an email, which is what I wanted, but nothing is logged to the file.

Have I setup the filters incorrectly or is this the expected behaviour of nlog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this : You forget to use "'" for ${message} => '${message}'

```
<filters>
        <when condition="contains('${message}', 'Some message exception text' )" action="Ignore"/>
</filters>
```

Comment: It is better with explanation.

Comment: thanks, i'll mark as complete although its not helped my current situation, i dont think the problem lies with nlog